# SQL: Regex for replace query

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I have SQL table as UserInfo with columns [id, username, details]. I need to update a part of a string from the column details.

For example. details column will look like,

```
{"username":"user.sample@nomail.org","rollno":45,"gender":"male"}
```

P.S: In actual DB this column is really long with more details, for example, I quoted above few details.

Condition is that the username value in the details column should be the same as the value in the username column.

I have **n** number of records mismatching in the DB, meaning username column value is different from username information in the details column.

Ex

```
id - username - details
23 - new-user@nomail.org - {"username":"user.sample@nomail.org","rollno":45,"gender":"male"}
```

Hence I am trying to replace the "username": "value" in details column with the username column value

EX - Expected should be like,

```
id - username - details
23 - new-user@nomail.org - {"username":"new-user@nomail.org","rollno":45,"gender":"male"}
```

For updating UserInfo, I am trying like

```
update UserInfo
set details = replace(details, \Regex\ ,"username:"+ username)
where id not in (select id from UserInfo where details like '%'+userid+'%' )
```

I need to regex pattern matching, ["username":"mail-id"], so that I can able to replace that particular string in that details column.

Any idea/suggestion for the regex pattern would be helpful

Comment: Nearly all database products support JSON functions these days. e.g. in Postgres you can use `jsonb_set()` to replace a value for a key in a JSON column.

Comment: sql-server @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: SQL-SERVER 2016 and it is not supporting JSON functions :(

Comment: @JG'sSpark Strange, SQL Server 2016 supports JSON (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: I am sorry it is 2008.

Comment: I have run JSON functions on these and got not supported error as well